# How to insert multiple queries with primary and foreign keys in nodejs mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So, I have a table called `movie` in which I am inserting the `movieID`, `name`, `rating`, and `overview`.
Now, I have another table called `Favorites` in which I am inserting the username (`users_username` column), movieID (`movie_movieID` column), and `description` (it is a descriptive column, different from overview). Here's the code:

```
db.query("INSERT  INTO movie (movieID, name, rating, overview) VALUES (?,?,?,?); INSERT INTO Favorites (users_username, movie_movieID, description)",
[id, name, rating, overview, username, id, description], (err,res)=>{
    // console.log(err)
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        response.send(res)
    }
})
```

Note that, the `users_username` and `movie_movieID` are foreign keys. The `users_username` is the primary key of another table while `movie_movieID` is the primary key of the `movie` table ( i.e., `movieID` column) .

However, only the first query is being executed. There is no data inserted in second query.

Is the data not being inserted in the second table due to the presence of foreign keys or what? Any hep would be appreciated!

Comment: Are any errors returned after executing the query?

Comment: Could you update the question and provide your definition for your database connection (`db`)? Do you set the `multipleStatements` option to `true`?

Comment: Sorry i had a thing to do. Yes i did specify in my connection about multipleStatemenets to true.

Comment: Not anything specific, only sloe connection error is popping up. It's like the second query is just ignored.

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to include both queries in one command? You should definitely see some different behavior by running each query individually. Could be something strange going on due to the FK rules.

Comment: Ok, so Im stupid, I got the column names incorrect. It's inserting properly now lol